# Customising the Quick Info Section in the Content Editor of Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

Is it possible to customise the quick info section in the content editor to show additional information about the item?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be quite tricky. If you look at `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor` (in Sitecore.Client.dll), you'll see there is a `RenderQuickInfo` method. The HTML gets pieced together manually and is added to an EditorFormatter object as a literal control. All the classes involved are tightly integrated in to the application - there's no easily identifiable customisation point.

There are some pipelines associated with the rendering of the Content Editor,

- renderContentEditor
- getContentEditorFields
- getContentEditorSkin

But I don't think these will provide an easy way in.

In general, I always think that if Sitecore haven't made part of the application easily customizable, then they probably did it on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be a more js approach. The whole of the content editor is in the dom, albeit rather nested. It's slightly different but highlights the concept (http://blog.boro2g.co.uk/ever-edited-sitecore-web-db-mistake/).

I'd suggest if you use the example below in anger you make the xpath better - this was simply stolen from chrome dev tools.

As an example: with the following script pasted into the **content manager.aspx** file you can access some of the elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    window.onload=function(){ 
        var text = getElementByXpath('//*[@id="EditorPanel"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]');
        if (text) {
            text.innerText = "hi";
        } else {                
        }
    };        
    function getElementByXpath(path) {
        return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    }
</script>
```

Which then allows you to update text (see screenshot):
[quickinfo says hi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU0MB.png)

Comment: There is a bit more info available on http://blog.boro2g.co.uk/updating-the-sitecore-quick-info-panel/