# Want to show last updated by in item owner field of Quick info in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In the Quick info section of item, i want to show item owner field to be populated by the user who last updated that particular item instead of template owner's name by which that item has been created. foe example: I created an item named "ImageTest" from a template named "NewImage". The item owner of "NewImage" is "sitecore/abc" (one who created NewImage template). Then I filled values in some fields of "ImageTest" and saved this item. Now when i go to to this item the quick info section shows item owner "sitecore/abc" whereas "updated by" field in Statistics tab of that section shows my name. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You need to update Core database and move or duplicate the "updated by" in Statistics tab into "Quick info" section.

Comment: Hi jay! could you please elaborate how can I do this?

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250214/customising-the-quick-info-section-in-the-content-editor-of-sitecore

Comment: Hey Martin.. I read this post already but it didn't help me!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the link in comments the quick info section is tightly coupled.

You could create your own quick info section. In its simplest form could be a field section with read only fields. Tap into the on save event and update the information accordingly.

You could also configure your users roles so that the standard Sitecore quick info section does not display and your custom one does.

The Quick Info section appears by default for Sitecore administrators and members of the Sitecore Client Developing role in the Sitecore security domain.

Other users need to elect to show the Quick Info section.

[image]

[image]